# DllNotFoundException while using unity native c++ Plugins

Tags: c++, macos, unity-game-engine

Getting DllNotFoundException when trying to build a native c++ plugin for Unity.

FirstDll.cpp

```
#include "FirstDll.h"                                                                                                                                                                

  DLLExport int add(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
  }

  FirstDll::FirstDll(){
  }

   FirstDll::~FirstDll(){
 }
```

FirstDll.h

```
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)                                                                                                                                              

   extern "C"{
       DLLExport int add(int a, int b);
   }

  class FirstDll{
  public:
       FirstDll();
      ~FirstDll();
 };
```

I am then generating a so file via this command

```
g++ -dynamiclib -flat_namespace -fms-extensions FirstDll.cpp -o libmyclass.so
```

I am then added this .so file in Assets/Plugins/x86_64 folder and in my unity c# code, I am trying to run this piece of code.

```
[DllImport("myclass")]
    static extern int add(int a, int b);
```

After getting this error, I have tried to moved the so file to different locations and test. I am always getting DllNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following clang command instead

```
clang *.cpp -O3 -dynamiclib -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o libmyclass.bundle
```

Then make sure to select the correct platform in Unity
[image: platform selection]

Or you can check this simple plugin from Unity: [SimplestPluginExample](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/DesktopSamples/tree/master/SimplestPluginExample)

Comment: The plugin works fine in Unity Editor. But when I build Android apk and try to run it, then getting this error
```
02-21 11:43:00.454  6297  6310 E Unity   : Unable to find ASimplePlugin
02-21 11:43:00.803  6297  6310 E Unity   : DllNotFoundException: ASimplePlugin
02-21 11:43:00.803  6297  6310 E Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) PluginImport.PrintANumber()
02-21 11:43:00.803  6297  6310 E Unity   :   at PluginImport.Start () [0x00000] in <fb0372b6d3eb4a80849b26b2b5598526>:0
```

Comment: You need to build the native plugins for each platform before trying to run. For Android, you need the NDK setup.

Comment: I have installed NDK in unity for Android platform and my .so file is working fine now in Unity Editor, but when running in Android device, still getting the same error

Comment: Did you used the ndk-build.cmd to build the Android .so file? The native plugin needs to be built specifically for android. You can check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EElBAGkjPt4